# Can't find jersey-core for jersey 2 maven

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I have ported to jersey 2 as Dropwizard 1.1.0 is compatible with jersey 2 only, now the problem is,  I have found every extension jar of jersey 2 on maven central repository but not jersey-core, I have updated all other jersey extensions to 2.25.1, although maven says that the artifact is moved to org.glassfish.jersey.core but doesn't give the artifact id.
This group contains only these 3 jars:

[image]

Comment: It's jersey-common now. If you're using DW, you dropwizard-core will pull all the Jersey deps in, so you should have to be worrying about manually adding Jersey stuff in, unless it's not pulled in by DW (all the basic stuff is pulled in though).

Comment: thanks, the packages has been changed for the classes which jersey-core was containing, needed to change that which fixed my problem